# Unity constructor injection with different values

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've got a queue class, Queue that implements IQueue.
However I've got different environments, like Prod and UAT (and need to use both of them at the same time). The Queue class takes in some configuation which is different for each environment.

I know how to wire up the constructors for IQueue, but don't know whats the best way to do so I can get different constructor values.

```
container.RegisterType<IQueue<>, Queue>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(_serverAddress);
```

With the above, it specifies a server address to use for the Queue constructor.

Problem is I need two instances of the queue, say a queue thats been configured for Prod and another for UAT, which have different server addresses this is used as a dependency in another class eg:

```
 PackageController(IQueueProd prodQueue, IQueueUAT uatQueue)
```

do I have to create different interfaces just so I can wire up different constructors? Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: This seems very odd to me. Why do you need both queues at the same time in the application. Either your application is running in production OR it is running in the acceptance environment; never both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is to use named registrations, i.e.

```
container.RegisterType<IQueue, Queue>("Prod", new InjectionConstructor(_prodServerAddress));
container.RegisterType<IQueue, Queue>("UAT", new InjectionConstructor(_uatServerAddress));

container.RegisterType<PackageController>(
   new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IQueue>("Prod"), 
                            new ResolvedParameter<IQueue>("UAT")));
```

This registers two type mappings of the `IQueue` interface, one for Prod and one for UAT, this also registers a type mapping for the `PackageController` which will inject the Prod `IQueue` and the UAT `IQueue`.